# How to use PlusMinus properly?

Tags: plotting, functions

As an easy exercise, I would like to define a function

$$f(x)=\pm x$$

and be able to ListPlot the function for some discrete values.

Here is what I tried

```
F[x_] := PlusMinus[x];
Table[F[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

This gives me output

```
{\[PlusMinus]1, \[PlusMinus]2, \[PlusMinus]3, \[PlusMinus]4}
```

This is exactly what I want. But now I want to listplot it using

```
ListPlot[Table[F[x], {x, 1, 4}]]
```

But this does not give me output.

So, I guess my question is how to convert the output of `PlusMinus[2]` which is $\pm2$ to an array $\{-2,2\}$ so that I can do other operations on it.

Comment: [`PlusMinus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlusMinus.html) has no built-in meaning apart from the typesetting. Do you want [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) instead?

Comment: Why don't you just define F as `F[x_] := {x, -x}` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the documentation, you could define the function for `PlusMinus`:

```
PlusMinus[a_] := {-a, a}
\[PlusMinus]2
(* {-2,2} *)
ListPlot[Table[\[PlusMinus]i, {i, 4}]]
```

[image]